# Dart:convert fails to decode JSON string: TypeError

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am getting the following string through an API request:

```
{
    "id": 21,
    "description": null,
    "creationDate": "2020-01-20T00:00:00",
    "status": "string",
    "open": false,
    "confirmedBy": null,
    "solvedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "repairedBy": null,
    "works": false,
    "brokenParts": [],
    "wellId": 9
}
```

Now, I try to create an object from this:

```
var result = json.decode(response.body);
```

I receive the following error:

`type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Why does this happen? The JSON is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When receiving information from an online source, it's actually not a String variable you're receiving (even though it can be printed that way, it's not formatted correctly).  It's actually what's called a "response" variable.  And you need to convert that to a Map to be able to break it up into Strings.

For Example:

```
Map result = jsonDecode(response.body);
String tempString = result['id'];
```

Would get you the value of the "id" variable inside the Map.